# Angular get fullname

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a demo jsonp data

```
    var APP = angular.module('JsonApp', []);

    APP.controller('TheCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {

      $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?rows=30&id={index}&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&sales={number|100}&bonus={number|10}&orderday={date|10-10-2014,10-12-2015}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.users = data;
      })


    }])
```

The data just have first name and last name, how can i get the fullname like 
fullname = fname + lname

and my template is

```
{{user.fullName}}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
{{user.fName + " " + user.lName}}
```

You could also simply write

```
{{user.fName}} {{user.lName}}
```

Comment: Yea,i was write this before, but how i try is join two data become a one data.

thanks.